# Informatica Lookup String Pattern Matching

Tags: lookup, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a Lookup table (loaded from a user flat file) with 2 columns only  , one being the joining column and the other being the desired output.

My source data column A is having sample data like follows:

999-55555-000-400-9999

800-22222-123-777-2233

and so on... 500K Records.

Now Lookup table is as follows:

Column B         ||   Column C

999-X-000-400-X || John

X-22222-X-777-X || Smith

Requirement is if Source Column A data matches the format of Lookup Table's Column B data, it will return the value from Column C as output.

How can I achieve this via LKP and Expression Transformation (Not using Java as I am not well versed with it). If the LKP table needs additional column that can be added as I am loading data from the flat file there. Will appreciate if someone can assist on this?

Comment: Are you looking for matching format in ColumnA and lkp.ColumnB ? And not the data. In your example, which values lkp should return  - row 1 should return John becaues lkp contains 999-X-000-400-X - where only 999-, -000-400 these two substrings  are matching? What if colA has data like this "999-ABC" - is it a match? So its like pattern match but not exactly pattern match. We may have to split and and then do pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply mark you column B and Column A as your lookup port in lookup transformation and Column C as output port.

That's all you need to do. Remember one thing lookup transformation works as left outer join on your data set. So if value in columnA matches with ColumnB then ColumnC would be returned else you will get null.

Comment: Thanks Divyaansh, but my issue here is LKP doesnt have LIKE operator for me to use. My input data is a full string with all numbers separated by hyphen as follows: 111-222-333-444-555 but my lookup column B will have data like 111-X-222-333-X . So how can I get my Source field to match with the LKP data pattern where the data will have X inplace of actual numbers.

Comment: You can use regexp_replace either in SQ transformation or in an expression to convert your source data as it present in your ff(lookup data).

Comment: You can use regexp_replace either in SQ transformation or in an expression to convert your source data as it present in your ff(lookup data).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this search with some preparation of your data. After field splitting, you will not need the `LIKE` operator, but only exact matching on sub-fields.

For the Lookup data, change the Column B into 5 columns :

```
B1 || B2  || B3  || B4  || B5 || Column C
999 || X || 000 || 400 || X || John
X || 22222 || X || 777 || X || Smith
```

For the input data, make a similar splitting :

```
IN1 || IN2 || IN3 || IN4 || IN5
999 || 55555 || 000 || 400 || 9999
800 || 22222 || 123 || 777 || 2233
```

Now you will have to use... 5 Lookups, one of each sub-field

```
Lkp1
Condition : IN1 = B1
Output : Match1_B1, Match1_B2, Match1_B3, Match1_B4, Match1_B5, Match1_Column_C

Lkp2
Condition : IN2 = B2
Output : Match2_B1, Match2_B2, Match2_B3, Match2_B4, Match2_B5, Match2_Column_C
```

And so on to 5

For the first line you will get :

```
Match1_B1 : 999
Match1_B2 : X
Match1_B3 : 000
Match1_B4 : 400
Match1_B5 : X
Match1_Column_C : John
Match2_B1 : NULL
Match2_B2 : NULL 
Match2_B3 : NULL
Match2_B4 : NULL
Match2_B5 : NULL
Match2_Column_C : NULL
Match3_B1 : 999
Match3_B2 : X
Match3_B3 : 000
Match3_B4 : 400
Match3_B5 : X
Match3_Column_C : John
Match4_B1 : 999
Match4_B2 : X
Match4_B3 : 000
Match4_B4 : 400
Match4_B5 : X
Match4_Column_C : John
Match5_B1 : NULL
Match5_B2 : NULL 
Match5_B3 : NULL
Match5_B4 : NULL
Match5_B5 : NULL
Match5_Column_C : NULL
```

Now in an Expression you link all the Lookups and check if the sub-fields match :

```
IIF( (ISNULL(Match1_B1) OR Match1_B1 != 'X')
AND (ISNULL(Match2_B2) OR Match2_B2 != 'X')
AND (ISNULL(Match3_B3) OR Match3_B3 != 'X')
AND (ISNULL(Match4_B4) OR Match4_B4 != 'X')
AND (ISNULL(Match5_B5) OR Match5_B5 != 'X'),
    IIF(ISNULL(Match1_Column_C),
        IIF(ISNULL(Match2_Column_C),
            IIF(ISNULL(Match3_Column_C),
                IIF(ISNULL(Match4_Column_C),
                    Match5_Column_C,
                    Match4_Column_C
                ),
                Match3_Column_C
            ),
            Match2_Column_C
        ),
        Match1_Column_C
    )
)
```

That should be near what you want, I hope !